# Create DNS Host A and Pointer records from a list

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dns

At my work we are going to be doing a disaster recovery test. I am attempting to make 4 batch files. One that deletes the existing server Host A and Pointer records. One that creates the new updated entries. One that removes the new entries, and then one that creates the originals that were in place. So far this is what I have.

1.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%1 in (C:\Host.txt) do dnscmd LogonServer /RecordAdd abc.org %%1 A %%2
```

2.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%1 in (C:\Host.txt) do dnscmd LogonServer /RecordDelete abc.org %%1 A %%2
```

These work okay except that they do not create or remove the pointer records and the second one (the one to remove the records) prompts me for a y/n to delete for each record in the list. Any assistance would be appreciated. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: I bet if you read the help file for the command you will figure out how to make it not prompt you to delete the record.

Comment: Assistance with what? What specifically do you want us to help you with? We don't write code for you, but if you tried something and after some research can’t understand how to do that specific thing, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of the Host A record names, the domain name and the IP's you would like to add or delete(no spaces) separated by ;'s. Replace "SERVERNAME" in the code below with the DNS Server name. To remove records change the "RecordAdd" to "RecordDelete" Add "/f" to the end of the code when deleting to silence y/n prompts.

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=;" %%a in (C:\list.txt) do for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%e in ("%%c") do dnscmd SERVERNAME /RecordAdd %%g.%%f.%%e.in-addr.arpa. %%h PTR %%a.%%b

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=;" %%a in (C:\list.txt) do dnscmd SERVERNAME /RecordAdd %%b %%a A %%c
```